Audio stuttering in Ubuntu 24
Audio is stuttering in Ubuntu 24.After the fresh install of Ubuntu. Audio is stuttering.Youtube and other apps are not working properly

This question is similar to: Screen suddenly flashes, becomes grainy and shows visual artifacts. "If you ever get repeating audio loops and a frozen screen together when playing an online video, that confirms it." If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
